# mkl_service.h header missing from anaconda mkl install

Tags: anaconda, intel-mkl

```
conda install -c intel mkl
```

Installs MKL. But now, I proceed to compile code which depends on mkl, and I point it to my anaconda:

```
MKLROOT=.../path/to/env/my_env/lib
```

Where many mkl library files now reside.

However, I get a message indicating `mkl_service.h` is missing. So I install `conda install anaconda mkl-service`.  However, this does not yield the missing header file.

How do I acquire this missing file in the anaconda version of MKL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my installation I had to do a

`$ conda install mkl-include`

After that I added the directory
`<path_to_conda_installation>\conda\envs\<env_name>\Library\include`
to the include_path (in the setup.py file).

Comment: You would think that would be part of the conda MKL install.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the problem recently, and succeded with

```
conda install mkl-include
```

and added

```
export CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/path_to_conda/envs/env_name/include
```

in ~/.bashrc

The version I am using is Nvidia pytorch release 21.06:py-3 (has ubuntu 20.04)